# letter getting cutt off when I use a counter in do while loop c++

Tags: c++, arrays, increment, getline

I'm trying to use a counter in my do while loop but if i do it cuts off the first letter of my getline in the first iteration

Here is the do while loop..

```
do
{
    cout << "Enter the name of your class: " << endl;
    cin.get();
    getline(cin, classnames[i]);

    cout << "Enter how many units was the class: " << endl;
    cin >> classunits[i];

    cout << "Enter the grade you completed the class with: " << endl;
    cin >> classgrades[i];
    classgrades[i] = toupper(classgrades[i]);

    i++;

} while (again());
```

For instance if I enter `english` the `'e'` will be cut off in the first iteration but any next iteration `english` will show fine.

this only happens when I add the `i++`

I've tried `cin.ignore()` but I still can't seem to crack it!

Comment: Well `cin.get()` reads a character. It's probably that.

Comment: Why are you using this `cin.get()`? It's just reading a character and discarding it

Comment: hm when i remove that when it loops it displays both enter the name/enter how many units. 
sorry im still pretty new haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `cin.get()` at the beggining and add `cin.ignore()` at the end:

```cpp
do
{
    cout << "Enter the name of your class: " << endl;
    // cin.get();  // remove
    getline(cin, classnames[i]);

    cout << "Enter how many units was the class: " << endl;
    cin >> classunits[i];

    cout << "Enter the grade you completed the class with: " << endl;
    cin >> classgrades[i];
    classgrades[i] = toupper(classgrades[i]);

    cin.ignore(); // add
    i++;

} while (again());
```

Comment: hey yeah thanks 
now when I do that when it loops it will display enter the name of you class and enter how many units was the class at the same time before it lets the user input for the first one

Comment: @noobex: What does your `again` function do?

Comment: it asks the user if they would like to repeat all that again for another class they took. looking at that function made me see that it also needed a cin,ignore();
Thanks for the help !! :)

Comment: @noobex: I asked that, because it is possible that `again()` function leave something in the input stream and can harm input in the loop (where `getline` reads classnames' name)... so, consider duplication of `cin.ignore()` in the end (before `return`) of `again`'s body.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, cin.get() extracts and returns the first character in the input stream which you are discarding.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `cin.get();`. It reads the first character you enter and does not even store it anywhere, and thus the first character you entered is not stored in the string.